# How to stop Lex from outputing whitespace to stdout for every rule

Tags: c++, flex-lexer, lex

In my .l file, I have set several rules using regex like below

```
%{
  #include <string.h>
%}

%%
[0-9]* {string.append("something");
return 1;}   

[^\n]*   /*ignore*/
```

Given the code above, the program generates white space to the terminal for every time it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore whitespace, ignore whitespace :) :

```
[[:space:]]+      ;
```

(That will also ignore newlines, so you can use it instead of the newline rule.)

By default, (f)lex uses the default rule `ECHO;` for any unrecognised character. If that is not what you want (and it usually isn't except for transducers), then put

```
%option nodefault
```

in your prolog, and flex will warn you if there is any pattern which might not be matched by one of your rules.